# SQL using parenthesis to include multiple criteria after WHERE

Tags: sql

I am wondering if it's possible for us to use parenthesis to include multiple criteria after WHERE. For example, I am looking for data from multiple dates, and original code looks like this,

```
SELECT * FROM MyDB
WHERE Date = '2016-06-30' OR Date = '2016-09-30' OR Date = '2016-12-31'
```

This code will be extremely long if I will need to get data from more time periods, or column name is long and complex. I tried to change the code into the following format and apparently it's not correct,

```
SELECT * FROM MyDB
WHERE Date = ('2016-06-30', '2016-09-30', '2016-12-31')
```

I am wondering if there is a way we can code in the method I described above so that it can get me data from all dates (or other criteria)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using `IN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM MyDB
WHERE Date IN ('2016-06-30', '2016-09-30', '2016-12-31')
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It didn't turn obvious to me until you pointed it out. Thanks for the hint!